# Drupal 7 Views Contextual Links edit Nodes and Fields

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

I created some Views with Drupal 7 and also installed the module Contextual Links. It helps me to edit Views and Blocks. But for non-admin users like Editors etc. it would be great to even edit Nodes or Fields with Contextual Links.

So I hover a Field there should appear a Edit Link.

I couldn't find any detailed settings for Contextual Links.

Please tell me how to set this up.

Comment: Try this solution: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58052/editing-fields-presented-in-a-view-in-drupal-7/58061#58061

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, contextual links for the node are displayed only when you choose "Unformatted" as style and "Node" as row style. I already posted a [feature request](http://drupal.org/node/1019486) to allow adding contextual links when the row style is "Fields".