# Editing fields presented in a view

Tags: 7, views

I am looking for a module that allows fields to be edited that are presented<,
preferably by a view. Basically what I am trying to acheive is as follows:

1. I have a content type as Meter Readings
2. Meter reading prepopulates by entity reference_prepopulate to a parent project
     ie.Building.
3. Idea is that a building has a meter say Electricity meter that records
     electricity readings(by Meter Readings Content type) that is presented in a view

I want to add meter readings in the view itself and not let the user to go to another screen,

Any  module to do this? Any references would be of great help.

Comment: are you creating one node per meter reading or adding additional mete reading to the existing content?

Comment: @MohammedShameem adding meter readings on a monthly basis like for jan -december , fields should be added as per user choice like add on more entry type thing, adding readings to existing content

Comment: Let me know if the method I explained works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use the [field collection.](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) and [field collection views](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views)

This would automatically create the add edit and delete links to those who have permission to do so both in views as well as node view. It will popup a nice box to make the changes or add items.

I followed the following steps.

1. Added a content type called Meter Reading
2. Added a field collection called Reading with widget embedded made its value as unlimited.
3. Add a field to the field collection.
4. Added a content of the type Meter Reading without entering anything in the reading.

Now when you visit the newly created content you would get something like below image.

[image]

Here you will notice the add link this and when you click that you would get a popup something like in the below screenshot.

[image]

In the popup you can enter the readings.

This is what I get after entering couple of readings.

[image]

By the way you can add field collection with in field collection and it would work the same. So in your case instead creating a content type called Meter reading you can create a field collection called meter reading and then add a field collection with in that called readings and with in that add a field called Reading.

So your entire page would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

am looking around D7 options myself- sounds like editable fields would suit your need to - shame it is only alpha - http://drupal.org/project/editablefields

Comment: Editable fields doesnt work with field collections